# Is it possible to use uglifyjs from a batch file (command prompt)? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, windows, uglifyjs

I have never used nodejs and would prefer not to tackle that right now. I have been using yui compressor for years and really love the MSBuild project YUICompressor.NET. But I want to start using uglifyjs instead.

1. Is it possible to use uglifyjs without nodejs?
2. Is it possible to use uglifyjs from the command line?
3. Is there an easy way (MSBuild project ideally) to use uglifyjs with Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get an answer to your question "If so, how"?

Comment: I installed the package through nodejs and I use the `<Exec>` command in msbuild to run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is, but the command-line tool is designed for NodeJS.
2. Yes, but see (1).
3. Nothing that I know of.  It's possible in theory to wire it up into any IDE, but nobody has done it so far.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for getting back to me!